# How to force Facebook Linter to rescrape page with cookies enabled?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, session-cookies, facebook-likebox, http-redirect

I've been having a lot of problems with Facebook Like button lately. Specifically, when the user clicks Like button, the comment dialog does not show up, but instead an error link saying that "page could not be reached".

When Facebook Linter scrapes such a page, it gets a 302 which redirects linter to a URL with `jsessionid=xxx` appended. I assumed that Facebook handles 302 correctly and decided to configure Tomcat to store `jsessionid` as a cookie. Here is an example: http://galecsy.com:88/lrm/ms/oid/75009

I also assumed that Facebook Linter can handle cookies, because there is a `cookies:true` parameter to `FB.init()` as explained here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

However, linter does not seem to preserve `jsessionid` cookie when it follows the 302 redirect. So, is there a way to force linter to respect cookies? If not, what is this `cookies:true` parameter on JS SDK for?

Answer (score 0):

> what is this cookies:true parameter on JS SDK for?

It makes the SDK store information about the login status in a cookie, so that it can easily be accessed on the server side on the next request (f.e. by the PHP SDK).

> So, is there a way to force linter to respect cookies?

I don’t think so.

You should make your app work without requiring cookies.

Comment: My app can work without requiring cookies. However, if the user, such as Facebook lint, does not have a session and tries to access page1 the app will do a 302 redirect to page1?jsessionid=xxx which recently started to throw FB Like button off as described in this bug https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/391962640871463. I am just trying to find a workaround for this bug.

Comment: How do you issue a new user a jsessionid and don't redirect? Besides, won't you agree that something is wrong with Facebook if it doesn't follow 302 redirects?

Comment: _“won't you agree that something is wrong with Facebook if it doesn't follow 302 redirects?”_ – it _does_ follow them. But from what it looks like, on your page the whole thing ends up in a circular redirect, _because_ you require the client to accept cookies. I don’t see a need to redirect to issue a new session id. PHP for example can handle this fine without redirecting.

Comment: Sorry, the website in my original post tried to use cookies. Here is a website which does not use cookies and illustrates the original "page could not be reached" problem I am suffering from https://www.customerelite.com/lrm/ms/oid/595505 
Note that linter processes it just fine.

Comment: _“Note that linter processes it just fine.”_ – not really, when I pass that URL through the debug tool it says, “URL redirected too many times. Please reduce the number of redirects.” And that’s because it redirects to an URL with a new session id on each request.

Comment: Make sure you are debugging the URL from my previous comment. Here is a link which shows that Facebook debugger processed it just fine: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.customerelite.com%2Flrm%2Fms%2Foid%2F595505
However Like button on the page does not work.

Comment: If you look at the debugger output, you see a line saying _“URL for Likes: https;//www.customerelite.com/lrm/ms/oid/595505.0;jsessionid=C520CB8FAD9910FBBE96A6A97EFD4FF5”_ – so it has your session id included, and of course if _that_ URL is the one that get’s chosen for likes, it will mess things up for the next real user, who will of course have _another_ session id. _Stop redirecting to __different__ URLs_ – that’s the only sensible solution I can see here.